# connecting SQL Server with Intellij

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea, javafx

So i'm working on SQL Server and i finally connected SQL Server to Intellij
but now i tried to run this code and it gives me errors that Login failed for user and i tried to write the code as

```
String connection1 = "jdbc:sqlserver://ONE:1433;databaseName=IntellijDB";
```

and as

```
String connection1 = "jdbc:sqlserver:IntellijDB";
```

and I've tried everything i could've done 
i hope you help me 
Experts HELP!!

[Server Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8vpv.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMDPQ.png)

Comment: You have checked `Windows domain auth`. Are you sure your app runs as the same user?  You should try old fashion (username/password approach).

Comment: yeah thanks, it worked but do you know why windows auth didn't work ?
btw, my app is running in the same user